# PrimeNG 6.0.0-rc1 TreeTable cannot expand rows

Tags: icons, primeng, primeng-treetable

I have the same problem as this [PrimeNG forum post](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=55960).

Basically the TreeTable component correctly reads the tree but the

> `<p-treeTableToggler [rowNode]="rowNode"></p-treeTableToggler>`

isn't somehow supported which is the arrow to expand the rows

> 'p-treeTableToggler' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'p-treeTableToggler' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'p-treeTableToggler' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>    to suppress this message.

I'm really confused how it is working on the PrimeNG showcase but not for me and a couple people that post in the PrimeNG forum.

Comment: did u include treeTableToggler Module in your main ts file?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [Treetable source code](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/6.0.0-rc.1/src/app/components/treetable/treetable.ts#L2266), they are using *primeicons* like `pi pi-fw pi-chevron-down` :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'p-treeTableToggler',
    template: `
        <a href="#" class="ui-treetable-toggler" *ngIf="rowNode.node.leaf === false || rowNode.level !== 0 || rowNode.node.children && rowNode.node.children.length" (click)="onClick($event)" [style.visibility]="rowNode.node.leaf === false || (rowNode.node.children && rowNode.node.children.length) ? 'visible' : 'hidden'" [style.marginLeft]="rowNode.level * 16 + 'px'">
            <i [ngClass]="rowNode.node.expanded ? 'pi pi-fw pi-chevron-down' : 'pi pi-fw pi-chevron-right'"></i>
        </a>
    `
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest primeNg then make sure that you have the primeicons and css style also loaded. Without this I wasn't getting the tree structure for the data.  Like treetable component, if you don’t import primeicons, the `>` chevron-right wont’t display.

```
 yarn add primeicons or npm install primeicons –save
```

and modify vendor.scss:

```
add @import "~primeicons/primeicons.css";
```